# I am getting problem in reverse url of python Django1.11.4 for creating the web application

Tags: python, html, django, vs-web-application-project

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without
providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module,
or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

I have tried a number of different variants

please take a look at my code:

I have a urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import home_page, about_page, room_page, login_page, register_page
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page),
    url(r'^home/$', home_page),
    url(r'^about/$', about_page),
    url(r'^room/$', room_page),
    url(r'^login/$', login_page),
    url(r'^register/$', register_page),
    url(r'^products/', include("products.urls", namespace='products')),
    url(r'^youadmin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py-myapp

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import (
    ProductListView, 
    ProductDetailSlugView, 
    )
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductDetailSlugView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

A card.html

```
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  {% if instance.image %}

    <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ instance.title }} logo"></a>
    {% endif %}
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ instance.title }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">view</a>
    <!-- <a href="{% url 'products:detail' slug=instance.slug %}" class="btn btn-warning">URL shortc</a> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

A models.py

```
import random
import os
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from .utils import unique_slug_generator
from django.urls import reverse
def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splittext(base_name)
    return name, ext
def upload_image_path(instance, filename):
    print(instance)
    print(filename)
    new_filename = random.randint(1, 3455645632)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return "Products/{new_filename}/{final_filename}",format(
        new_filename=new_filename, 
        final_filename=final_filename
        )
class Product(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField()
    price           = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/products/{slug}/".format(slug=self.slug)
        return reverse("products:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title   
def product_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)
pre_save.connect(product_pre_save_receiver, sender=Product)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you've got is self-explanatory.

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#include

```
include(module, namespace=None, app_name=None)
include(pattern_list)
include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)
include((pattern_list, app_namespace, instance_namespace))
```

as per error message, you should rely on 3rd option

i assume you called your app `products`

```
..
    url(r'^products/', include(('products.urls', 'products'), namespace='products')),
..
```

Comment: still I am getting a new error can you please help me in this

TypeError: include() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app_name'

Comment: @AAKASHSINGLA i'm sorry , just remove `app_name=`, there's no need of this keyword, i'm confused, i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but now I am getting error in card.html

**NoReverseMatch**

my card.html file
'''
 
  {% if instance.image %}
   <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}"><img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ instance.title }} logo"></a>
       <a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary">view</a>
    <!-- <a href="{% url 'products:detail' slug=instance.slug %}" class="btn btn-warning">URL shortcut</a> -->
  </div>
</div>
'''
please help me

Comment: in `get_absolute_url()` function you have two return statements ? try to comment the first one. and let see

Comment: try to change the 2 occurrence of `{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}` to `{% url 'products:detail' slug=instance.slug %}`